# getting frames from rtsp stream ffmpeg -- hang in av_read_play

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg, h.264, rtsp

I'm trying to use this code to get video frames from RTSP stream:

```
// Open the initial context variables that are needed
SwsContext *img_convert_ctx;
AVFormatContext* format_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
AVCodecContext* codec_ctx = NULL;
int video_stream_index;
// Register everything
av_register_all();
avformat_network_init();
if (avformat_open_input(&format_ctx, argv[1],
                        NULL, NULL) != 0) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if (avformat_find_stream_info(format_ctx, NULL) < 0) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
//search video stream
for (int i = 0; i < format_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
    if (format_ctx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        video_stream_index = i;
}

AVPacket packet;
av_init_packet(&packet);

//open output file
AVFormatContext* output_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
AVStream* stream = NULL;

//start reading packets from stream and write them to file
av_read_play(format_ctx);    // <-- program is frozen in this API call

// Get the codec
AVCodec *codec = NULL;
cout << "avcodec_find_decoder" <<endl;
codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);

// some more important stuff below ...
```

When I launch my program with MP4 file, it works correctly. If I use it with RTSP H264 stream it doesn't go blow av_read_play. Original ffmpeg binary works correctly with RTSP stream also. What may be the reason for this?

Comment: check my code, HTH : https://github.com/sailfish009/sample_decode/blob/master/sample_decode/MainDlg.cpp

Comment: Do you have any additional log-files or does it just hang? If you do not have any logfiles, what does wireshark or any other package logger say? Do you actually receive packages from the stream? I am asking since I made the experience (on other occasions) that networks time-outs caused strange behavior in C++.